# How do I set an objects position relative its parent?

Tags: coordinates

Does blender support parent relative coordinates?
How do I set an objects position relative its parent?

I am setting the coordinates of the ship (being a child of the bottle) to 0 0 0. Trying to change transform orientation of the 3d view gives no change, the ship goes to origin in any case.

[image: ship in bottle]

Comment: You want the ship to stay in a bottle?

Comment: I want to view/set the ships coordinates relative the bottle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to setup 0,0,0 coordinates at parent location.

[image]

The operator is called *Clear Origin*, for 2.8+ you can access it from the 3D View header menu under *Object > Clear > Origin*.

Comment: Which software did you use to create that presentation?

Comment: @AndersLindén it's byzanz with custom script from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/833973/16892). Keypad is KeyMon

Comment: What about rotation?

Comment: What's this called? It would be nice to have a name for the "alt O" procedure so I can find it in menus.

Comment: @foobarbecue Clear origin

Comment: This does not work for me in 2.79 or 2.8. Clear Origin works exactly the same way as Parent Without Inverse: it snaps the location of the child to the center of the parent. That is not what I want, nor presumably, what the OP wants, since it was initially stated that "the ship goes to origin in any case", indicating that such snapping to the parent is NOT desired behavior. This answer was marked as accepted. Does this mean it worked for the OP? Alt-o in 2.79 snaps the child to center of the parent. Object > Clear > Orgin in 2.83 snaps the child to the center of the parent. What am I missing?